# How to iterate through all pages in Space in Confluence Cloud using REST API in Python

Tags: python, confluence-rest-api

I have a set of pages for "SOW","Data from Client", "Deliverable", etc inside many Spaces. I am reading the Space Key from Excel and able to iterate through all Spaces. However, I'm unable to figure out a way to loop through each page inside the Space. I have to look at each one to see its type before uploading the right document. Can you please let me know how to do this.

wiki/rest/api/search?cql=space= " + keyName
Use this line for getting the Space. Extract the Json - res1 = response11.json() and loop through                 while x <= 6:
name = str(res1['results'][x]['title'])
However, this does not look for all the pages. In fact, it picks up the pages randomly.

I would appreciate it if you could give me a code snippet for performing this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure out how to do this.

Below is the API I am using -
wiki/rest/api/space/" + spaceName + "/content"

Following is the code I am using for iterating through each page -

```
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
response11 = requests.request("GET", url, auth=auth)
if response11.status_code != 404:
    res11 = response11.json()
    x = 0
    while x < len(res11['page']['results']):
        name = str(res11['page']['results'][x]['title'])
        x = x + 1
 time.sleep(6)
```

Comment: Apparently what I thought is not the solution. I want to find a way for iterating through the Json results returned after firing the Rest API. Please let me know if any of you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 2):

Even better answer is to extract the results from the REST API response and loop through them using this code -

```
            pages = res1['children']['page']['results']
            i = 0
            for p, page in enumerate(pages):
                if(projectName == str(page['title'])):
                    print("Page Name - " + str(page['title']))
                    pageID = page['id']
```